# Fill armadillo vec from HDF5 vector

Tags: c++, ubuntu, hdf5, armadillo

I am trying to read a vector from and HDF5 file into an Armadillo vector but I keep getting a seg fault at the reading stage. I'm not sure what I'm missing, it seems straight forward but I guess not... Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
int main(void)
{
    H5::H5File fid = H5::H5File("element_pattern.h5",H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
    H5::DataSet   dataset    = fid.openDataSet("freq_collect");
    H5::DataSpace dataspace  = dataset.getSpace();
    H5::StrType   datatype   = dataset.getStrType();

    const int rank = dataspace.getSimpleExtentNdims();
    hsize_t dims_out[rank];
    const int ndims = dataspace.getSimpleExtentDims( dims_out, NULL);
    
    vec freq_collect(zeros<vec>(dims_out[0]));
    

    dataset.read(&freq_collect, datatype, dataspace);

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

`&freq_collect` should be `freq_collect.memptr()`

`.memptr()` is raw pointer to memory and is the correct way to store the data